# Formula utilizing Look Up Field to User not comparing values correctly

Tags: apex, formula

The following code results in "", every single time. Even when the Id's match on the record. Why is this?

```
 if
(
SDR_Owner__r.Id = '0056A000002iMxjQAE',
"https://fb.pics/img/2019/05/31/Bruce.png",
if(
SDR_Owner__r.Id = '0056A000003CAM5QAO',
"https://fb.pics/img/2019/06/19/IMG_1089.jpg",
if
(
SDR_Owner__r.Id = '0056A0000024sU6QAI',
"https://fb.pics/img/2019/02/25/Maria.png",
if(SDR_Owner__r.Id = '0056A00000247I7QAI',
"https://fb.pics/img/2019/02/25/MarkG.png",
if(
SDR_Owner__c == '0056A000002iWyhQAE',
'https://fb.pics/img/2019/06/25/Matt.jpg',
if(
SDR_Owner__c ='0056A0000024JZuQAM',
'https://fb.pics/img/2019/03/29/Zoe.jpg',
""
)
)
)
)
)
)
```

Is it possible to compare lookup Id fields to strings?

Comment: If this is a formula field you're creating, try using the 15-digit version of the `UserId`. It's not well documented (at least from what I've found) where string comparisons to IDs like this require the 15- or 18-digit version of the ID. In process builder condition formulas, it seems to require the 18-digit version, but in formula fields, the 15-digit variety works while the 18- does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to show a photo of the record owner in a field? If that's the case then do the following:

- On the User record create a custom text field to store the photo URL (note there's a std sf field on user called `FullPhotoURL` but it isn't available in formulas.
- populate the field above with the URL for each owner
- On your object create a custom formula field `Image(Owner.Photo_field__c, "Owner")`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the CASE statement:

```
CASE(
  SDR_Owner__c,
  "0056A000002iMxjQAE", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/05/31/Bruce.png",
  "0056A000003CAM5QAO", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/06/19/IMG_1089.jpg",
  "0056A0000024sU6QAI", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/02/25/Maria.png",
  "0056A00000247I7QAI", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/02/25/MarkG.png",
  "0056A000002iWyhQAE", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/06/25/Matt.jpg",
  "0056A0000024JZuQAM", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/03/29/Zoe.jpg",
  "")
```

If, for some reason, this doesn't work, you can also use `CASESAFEID` to force 18-character mode:

```
CASE(
  CASESAFEID(SDR_Owner__c),
  "0056A000002iMxjQAE", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/05/31/Bruce.png",
  "0056A000003CAM5QAO", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/06/19/IMG_1089.jpg",
  "0056A0000024sU6QAI", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/02/25/Maria.png",
  "0056A00000247I7QAI", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/02/25/MarkG.png",
  "0056A000002iWyhQAE", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/06/25/Matt.jpg",
  "0056A0000024JZuQAM", "https://fb.pics/img/2019/03/29/Zoe.jpg",
  "")
```

Comment: Better to recommend an approach which removes the Id values altogether.